# Access SQL Join

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, brackets

There do not seem to be a lot of good / condensed instruction on how to properly use brackets to designate table names... and I'm running into several issues.  Hoping someone is willing / able to help me audit the following code:

```
SELECT 
  A.Ccode,
  A.[Doc Type],
  A.[Doc Number],
  A.[Cross Company],
  A.[Doc Date],
  A.[Posting Date],
  A.Period,
  A.[Doc Header Text],
  A.Reference,
  IIf([2019_01].Cross Company] Is Not Null, [cc.vendor], [doc.vendor]) AS [SAP#],
  IIf([2019_01.G/L]<>"201200", [2019_01.G/L], IIf([201200.G/L Acct] Is Not Null, [201200.G/L Acct], "500140")) AS [G/L Acct],
  A.[G/L],
  A.[Cost Center],
  A.[WBS Element],
  A.Order,
  A.Plant,
  A.[Purchase Doc],
  A.Line,
  A.[D/C],
  IIf([D/C]="s", [Amount in LC]*1, [Amount in LC]*-1) AS [Amount(USD)],
  A.USD,
  IIf([D/C]="s", [Amount in DC]*1, [Amount in DC]*-1) AS [Amount(Doc)],
  A.Curr,
  IIf([D/C]="S", [Original Tax Base LC]*1, [Original Tax Base LC]*-1) AS [Tax Base LC],
  A.[Loc Curr],
  IIf([D/C]="S", [Original Tax Base DC]*1, [Original Tax Base DC]*-1) AS [Tax Base DC],
  A.[Doc Cur],
  A.User,
  A.[Tax Code],
  A.[Tax Jurisdiction],
  A.[Entry Date]
INTO [Final 2019_01]
FROM 
(
  (
    2019_01 AS A 
    LEFT JOIN CC AS X ON A.[Cross Company] = X.[Cross Company]
  ) 
  LEFT JOIN Doc AS Y ON (A.[Doc Number] = Y.[Doc Number]) AND (A.Ccode = Y.Ccode)
)
LEFT JOIN 201200 ON (A.Line = [201200].Item) AND (A.[Purchase Doc] = [201200].[Purchase Doc])
WHERE 
(
  (
    (A.Period)="1"
  )
  AND 
  (
    (A.Reference) Not Like "*TREE*"
  )
  AND 
  (
    (
      IIf([2019_01.G/L]<>"201200", [2019_01.G/L], IIf([201200.G/L Acct] Is Not Null, [201200.G/L Acct], "500140"))
    ) Not Like 132100
  ) 
  AND 
  (
    (A.[G/L])<>"200100"
  )
);
```

Comment: Did you use the query designer to build? It will take care of syntax for you.

Comment: It's a pain to work with MS Access SQL, because it is so very different from all the other DBMS and so far from the SQL standard. You can never just copy and paste from the Internet, because it seems almost all queries are always a little different in MS Access. For learning SQL, any other DBMS should be better.

Comment: Anyway, no matter which DBMS, I suggest you avoid special table and column names like `[2019_01]`, `[201200]` and `[2019_01.G/L]`. You can use underlines to get readable names instead: `ON a.doc_number = y.doc_number`. And when using alias names for tables, use mnemonic ones. `Y` for `Docs`??? Why not `D`, the first letter? Another thing: the table name `2019_01` indicates a table for a specific year (even month?), which is probably a very bad data model. Dates are mere data and should make a new row in a table, not a new table in the database.

Comment: Working from a previous query which was Access was unable to convert into design view. The reason for the alias was to try to make the transition easier.  Beginning of alphabet for tables, end of the alphabet for other queries.  The size of the data tables are enormous which precludes using more than a month of data at a time (other systems generating the data are limited in their ability to generate / export) and the need for the information is also required monthly, so keeping the information discreet until summarized and consolidated has been the direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All identifiers in MS Access queries including table and field names used anywhere in SQL query (`SELECT` expressions, `JOIN` clauses, `WHERE` conditions, etc.) that contain the following must be escaped with either square brackets or backticks:

- Special characters anywhere in the name (e.g., `!@#$%^&*()~+`) including whitespaces. 
  Exception: the underscore, `_`, which can be used anywhere even at beginning of name.
- Begins with a number (e.g., `1234567890`)
- [Reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sql-reserved-words-b899948b-0e1c-4b56-9622-a03f8f07cfc8) (e.g., `BY`, `JOIN`, `YEAR`, `POSITION`, `NO`)

Several places in your query require it:

1. Tables

   ```
   [2019_01] AS A
   [201200]

   `2019_01` AS A
   `201200`
   ```
2. Columns with period qualifiers `[Table].[Column]`:

   ```
   [201200].[G/L Acct]

   `201200`.`G/L Acct`
   ```
3. Reserved words

   ```
   A.[User]
   A.[Order]

   A.`User`
   A.`Order`
   ```

Finally, best practice in any relational database from MS Access to SQLite to Oracle and Postgres is to avoid these situations and use only alphanumerics without spaces, symbols, or begins with numbers to name tables, columns, stored procedures, queries, views, and any other object.

Comment: Thanks I will comb through and see if I can identify where my syntax is incomplete

Comment: Mostly check `JOIN` clauses and `IIF` fields which if table and columns names requires escaping, you need two pairs of brackets: `[Table].[Column]`. Also, consistently use table aliases which you do for all tables but `[201200]`. Even better if you can, consider renaming these tables and fields due to above reasons and avoid future issues.

Comment: Thank you very much.  The direction regarding [table].[column] was simple and appreciated !  Moving forward I will make sure to take everyones advice to heart.  

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

MS Access joins are a nuisance. You must nest every join in a pair of parentheses:

```
FROM 
(
  (
    (
      [2019_01] AS A 
      LEFT JOIN CC AS X ON A.[Cross Company] = X.[Cross Company]
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN Doc AS Y ON A.[Doc Number] = Y.[Doc Number] AND A.Ccode = Y.Ccode
  )
  LEFT JOIN [201200] ON A.Line = [201200].Item AND A.[Purchase Doc] = [201200].[Purchase Doc]
)
WHERE A.Period = 1
  AND A.Reference NOT LIKE '*TREE*'
  AND IIf([2019_01.G/L] <> 201200, [2019_01.G/L], IIf([201200.G/L Acct] Is Not Null, [201200.G/L Acct], 500140)) <> 132100
  AND A.[G/L] <> 200100;
```

Comment: OP's issue is not parentheses `(` but brackets, `[` with many, many issues of unclosed identifiers. See `IIF` expression in your answer. The last parentheses pairing is actually not needed. So OP may have had that part correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are also missing a [ on:

```
IIf([2019_01].Cross Company] Is Not Null
```